# How to pass variables in TemplateBody section of Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Im trying to pass RegionName in the TemplateBody section but getting the error as "**Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [RegionName] in the Resources block of the template**".

Here is the yaml file which I'm using:

```
      TemplateBody: |
        Resources:
          CWEvent:
            Type: AWS::Events::Rule
            Properties:
              State: ENABLED
              Name: Rule
              Targets:
                - Arn: !Sub "arn:aws:events:${RegionName}:1234:event-bus/My-Bus"
                  Id: 'Event'
                  RoleArn:
                    !Join
                      - ""
                      - - "arn:aws:iam::"
                        - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                        - ":role/"
                        - "Role"
              EventPattern:
                source:
                  - "aws.ec2"
                detail-type:
                  - "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
                detail:
                  eventSource:
                    - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                  eventName:
                    - "RestoreSnapshotFromRecycleBin"
```

Also I cannot use S3 due to restriction so TemplateURL is out of picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the !Sub function it should fill in all your variables for you, so your TemplateBody line should look like

```
  TemplateBody: !Sub |
```

This would then fill in your variables before the stack is deployed, you might need to remove the other !Sub's you have inside the template for this to work.

Comment: Silly on my part, I totally missed that. Thanks Will.